# magento adjust product visible

Tags: magento, product

I have 2 new custom productattributes that enables or disables a product in the category list and product-detail page.Both are dates.
need to calculate if the current date is between the 2 custom dates.
if it is, the product must be enabled.
I can't find a place in the code to enable/disable a product in the category list and detail page. I don't want to fix this in a phtml.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: You can just disable (Status->disable) the product and then it won't show on category or detail pages?

Comment: my custom attributes(2) are 2 dates. i have to check if the current date is between the 2 dates. if so, the product must be disabled.

Comment: so, `if (currentDateBetweenTheTwoDates()) { $product->setStatus(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_DISABLED); }` ?

Comment: that with a cronjob of a event? i hoped that i can adjust the product model

Comment: This is 'just' adjusting the product model. I'm not sure what you mean with cronjob of an event?

Comment: in productmodel there is a function getStatus(). if i return 2, my product is shown in the productlist but not in product-detail

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to modify two things :

- the product collection in order to add the filtering on your two news attributes.. For that, for example, you can implement the event `catalog_block_product_list_collection` from `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List` (used in product listing and search) where you'll add your filtering with the function `$collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_code', $condition)`
- the product page itself. You can add your logic in order to display or not your product by multiple ways.. I would choose to implement the event `catalog_product_is_salable_after` in order to add your logic here and call `$product->isSalable()` in the template or controller...